# Simultaneous connection to LAN and WAN with filters

Tags: windows-7, proxy, lan, wan

I'm looking for a software helping me to solve a problem I have in my office network.
I have a laptop connected via LAN to local servers, webfarm servers, webfarm and internet. In this network I am behind a proxy that blocks some ports and IPS and all the time I have to ask to open them temporary.
In our office we also have a WIFI router connected to internet without any restriction. So if I want I can disconnect the LAN, connect WIFI and go wherever I want.

What I'm looking for is a way (or better a software) that let me to be connected with both interface (LAN and WAN) at the same time. By default I would use the LAN connection. With the software I would like to add filters by IP or domain or port that let me choose some kind of services to use the WAN connection instead.

So for example if I want to go to Google.it it would use the LAN. But I can add a filter for 8080 port and all the connection to 8080 services would use the WAN.
I would use it mainly with web browsers but I would like to use it also for other software like ftp or custom software.

To me it looks like a virtual network card. All the connection are handled by this virtual card that send traffic to LAN or WAN depending on filters.
I tried looking around but no luck.

Do you have any idea on how I can do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what exactly you are calling "filters" in the title. Does not sound like a technical term to me.

What I think I understood from your description is that you have a notebook computer with 2 network interfaces (WIFI and wired ethernet) which you would like to use simultaneously to access internal (LAN) and external (WAN) resources. If that's what you want - this goal can be quite easily achieved without using any extra software. You just need to setup static routing using `route` command.

The easiest configuration would be setting the WIFI (i.e. WAN) interface as your default interface and then adding static route to your LAN subnet via wired ethernet interface. The somewhat tricky part is configuring the DNS. Probably the easiest way would be to use an external DNS server and then just add all your local servers to your local `hosts` file.

Comment: Filter is not a technical term is just a way to describe what I need. No, I don't want to use LAN for Internal resources only. I want to use LAN for most of the connection. I want to use WIFI for example to go to any resources on port 5050 for example, or I want to use the wifi to go to the ip xxx.yyy.www.zzz or the domain www.mydomainviawifi.com.

Answer (score -1):

> #### to be connected with both interface (LAN and WAN) at the same time

This is not possible if both are on the same subnet.

If LAN-if has to be used to reach - same IP class - LAN webfarm and WIFI-if  has to be used to reach Google (or any other IP of a different class), just put WiFi-if connected router as your default gateway. To explain better this matter:

1. If your IP is on the same subnet of systemX, you can reach systemX without any problem
2. If your IP is on a different subnet respect of systemY, you need a defaultGWY (on your subnet)
3. you cannot have two if on the same subnet with different (or worst, same) defaultGWY, as you send just 1 packet through 1 if to reach destination.

This is made simple.

To do what you want you need two application proxy on two different hosts with two different internet access, as well as a set of rule on proxyA related to domains/IP it has to use proxyB to reach.

Comment: Why make life complicated when you have the route command?